# Changing selected value in a select option

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am Currently having trouble change the value of a drop down list. I am currently adding an item to my cart on https://www.reebok.com/us/cart. I am trying to change the quantity.

I am trying to rewrite my java code into javascript. With that being said.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* [@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/select")));
select.selectByVisibleText(5);
```

Currently works for me in java using the Selenium library. But in Javascript, I am having trouble emulating the same step. I have tried everything.

Edit: I have tried

```
var select= document.evaluate('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/select', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
select.selectedIndex=7;
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gl-dropdown-native__select-element')[0].value=7;
```

Comment: What are you using specifically? Please share your code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Setting the `value` will not work - you have to set the `selectedIndex`

Comment: That still does not work.

Comment: You have to trigger the event too. I just can't seem to figure out what event it is listening to. So after you do ``.value = 6;`` you need to then do ``.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`` however I can't figure out what event it is listening to. I even tried 'click' with no joy... However when I reveal the hidden select dropdown, I can see the value changing. It just doesn't trigger the change though :/

Comment: Yea, i guess the Java selectByVisibleText() method does that automatically?

Comment: Yeah, it may be firing the event needed to trigger the change. I just can't figure out the event needed on this one or the right function to trigger the event required :/

Comment: Try to do ```select.dispatchEvent('change')``` Here is the example:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me a TypeError of "Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget'" @Drag13

Comment: @JustinJ72, sorry, this should work: ```select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));```

Comment: @Drag13 Still does not work for me. I initialized select and then i did `select.selectedIndex=7;` and then used your code and it still did not work.

Comment: I've added an example, could you please check it?

Comment: Check the working solution

Comment: @Drag13 It works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working function to change the item in the basket. The issue was to found the handler and event type they rely on. It was `mouseup` and event directly in the window.

```
function changeItemTo(itermNumber) {
    const itemsSelector = '.gl-dropdown-custom__options button';
    const itemsElements = document.querySelectorAll(itemsSelector);
    if (itemsElements == null) throw new Error(`Selector ${itemsSelector} is wrong, nothing found`);
    const buttonForItem = itemsElements[itermNumber];
    if (buttonForItem == null) throw new Error(`Item with index: ${itermNumber} not found`);

    buttonForItem.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, }));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still does not work for me. I am on the reebok website and trying to change the quantity when an item is in my cart. I edited the class to reflect the select element on the reebok website. 
`const select = document.querySelector('.gl-dropdown-custom__select-element');`
`select.selectedIndex = 2;`
`select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: Much interesting, I will take a look)

Comment: Just one more question, how did you find find out that it was `mouseup` that it relied on?

Comment: With hard debug actually. I found that the click event was ignored and look into the app code. Luckily, they were so generous that provided maps file so it takes not too much time

Comment: Where can you find the maps files?

Comment: is it the c.go-mpulse.net url?

Comment: I am not sure, Chrome loaded it somehow for me

Comment: I see you are executing this code as if it were a button. How would you do it if it was an input field, for example the discount code field?

Comment: I would do the same, check handlers, and try to emulate them. For input, it should be ``'change``' or ```blur``` . Or maybe ```keyup```